# Поиск минимального элемента с условием

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, min

Решаю задачу, в которой создаю массив, заполненный изначально нулями, по ходу решения заполняю его. Нужно найти минимальный элемент массива, не равный нулю и вывести его индекс в исходном массиве. Можно ли это сделать функционально? В смысле, я знаю, что можно пройтись фором по всему массиву, но можно ли какой-то комбинацией встроенных функций сделать это?

Comment: Фором это самое оптимальное, остальные способы нужны для сокращения кода и скорости его написания. Так что пишите фором и не парьтесь,  тем более, что ваша проблема элементарна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да легко:

```
data = [3, 5, 0, 7, 2, 8, 4]

result = min(enumerate(data), key=lambda x: x[1] if x[1] != 0 else float('Inf'))[0]

print(result)
```

Так же, как и в решении с циклом `for`, этот вариант работает за один проход и не потребляет лишней памяти (по крайней мере, в достаточно актуальных версиях питона, где `enumerate` работает лениво).

Но читать и отлаживать такое гораздо сложнее, чем простой вариант с циклом. Поэтому используйте лучше цикл.

Comment: Иф елс можно заменить на or